# "I love for you to be on my team."

Tags: word-usage

I wanna know if this sentence below makes any sense.

> *"I love for you to be on my team."*

If the sentence above makes sense, please, tell me the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: It has an error.  If the listener is not on the team, you probably want "I would love for you to be on my team." (you can change "I would" to "I'd" if you want - it is a contraction)  If the listener is on the team already, you probably want "I love having you on my team."

Comment: thank you very much for telling me it make sense.

Comment: There are more ways - "I love that you are on my team." is common.  Similarly, there is "I love the fact that you are on my team." - and, "I love it, that you are on my team."  (It is hard to say what punctuation is best - maybe a hyphen instead of the comma, or nothing at all)  Another option, although a little less clear, is "I love you being on my team."  They are all the same.  But the ones that use "would" indicate the person is not on your team yet.  (another "would" version: "I would love to have you on my team.")

Comment: And to get a little more complicated, if you construct something like "I would love that you were on my team." then you need more... such as "I would love that you were on my team, if you were on my team." or "I would love it if you were on my team.", or "If you were on my team, I would love it."